# Putting text and a logo at the same level on a front page

Tags: graphics, front-matter

I want to put text and a logo at the same level on a front page. I tried to use `minipage` but I had an `option clash for package xcolor`:

```
\documentclass[english, a4paper, 12pt, twoside]{article} 

% -------------- Setup, do not change these ---------------
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc, url}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{minted} % Code highlighting
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm} % Mathematical packages
\usepackage{parskip} % Removing indenting in new paragraphs
\urlstyle{sf}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{subcaption} 
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{chngcntr} % needed for correct table numbering
\counterwithin{table}{section} % numbering of tables 
\counterwithin{figure}{section} % numbering of figures
\numberwithin{equation}{section} % numbering of equations
\hyphenpenalty=100000 % preventing splitting of words
\sloppy 
\raggedbottom 
\usepackage{xparse,nameref}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc} % Fotnotes are fixed to bottom of page
\usepackage{lipsum} % For genereating dummy text

% --------- You can edit from this point on --------


% ----- Appearance and language ----- 
\usepackage[english]{babel} % document language
\graphicspath{{Images/}{../Images/}} % path to images
\usepackage[margin=2.54cm]{geometry} % sets margins for the document
\usepackage{setspace}
\linespread{1.5} % line spread for the document
\usepackage{microtype}


% ----- Sections -----
\titleformat*{\section}{\LARGE\bfseries} % \section heading
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\Large\bfseries} % \subsection heading
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\large\bfseries} % \subsubsection heading
% next three lines creates the \paragraph command with correct heading 
\titleformat{\paragraph}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}
{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}


% ----- Figures and tables ----- 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[rightcaption]{sidecap}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption} % bold text for captions
\usepackage[para]{threeparttable} % fancy tables, check these before you use them
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw,svgnames]{xcolor}
%\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{hhline}

\fancypagestyle{frontpage}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
    \vspace*{1\baselineskip}
    \begin{figure}
        \begin{minipage}
            \fancyhead[R]{École supérieure 
    \linebreak       S8, Avril 2018\vspace*{5\baselineskip}}
        \end{minipage}
        \begin{minipage}
            \fancyhead[L]{ \includegraphics[width=2.5in]{logo.png}}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{figure}

}

\begin{document}

\include{NHH-Frontpage}
\end{document}
```

It seemed I missed an option while calling this xcolor package. But even after adding it the problem was still there. This was the error message:

```
l.69 \usepackage
                {hhline}
The package xcolor has already been loaded with options:
  [svgnames]
There has now been an attempt to load it with options
  [table,xcdraw,svgnames]
Adding the global options:
  svgnames,table,xcdraw,svgnames
to your \documentclass declaration may fix this.
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
```

Until now while coding it without `minipage` I had:

[image]

Comment: The option clash error is because you load the `xcolor` package twice and with different options (see line 17 and 65) Please also make our code a MWE that does not rely on external files that are not accessible to others.

Comment: @leandriis thanks I removed one line and added the options to the other. Regarding your second remark, as far as my question is about inserting an image, _the external file_ your talk about, what should I do to to create a MWE ? It can be any logo.jpg file anyway ...

Comment: @ThePassenger We don't have `NHH-Frontpage`, right? So how can we reproduce your problem?

Comment: @ThePassenger: Regarding the image: you could use `example-image` (one of the images included in latex distributions for testing purposes). But actually I was referring to the included file `NHH-frontpage` that we don't have access to.